# ng-init alway giving error in Browser Consolde

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mvvm

I am using ng-init expression  to assign value from selected dropdown to viewModel. functionality is working properly . but It's showing so many error in browser console. can any one please help me on this??

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Approve Status:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select ng-disabled="true" ng-init="{{obj.ApproveID=selectedApproveStatus.DropdownUtilityID}}" ng-model="selectedApproveStatus" data-ng-options="option.DropdownUtilityName for option in approveStatus track by option.DropdownUtilityID" class="form-control"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

---

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{obj.ApproveID=selectedApproveStatus.DropdownUtilityID}}] starting at [{obj.ApproveID=selectedApproveStatus.DropdownUtilityID}}].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=…%7D%7D&p4=%7Bobj.ApproveID%3DselectedApproveStatus.DropdownUtilityID%7D%7D
    at http://localhost:21845/Scripts/angular.js:68:12
    at Object.AST.throwError (http://localhost:21845/Scripts/angular.js:13057:11)
    at Object.AST.object (http://localhost:21845/Scripts/angular.js:13044:16)
    at Object.AST.primary (http://localhost:21845/Scripts/angular.js:12952:22)
    at Object.AST.unary (http://localhost:21845/Scripts/angular.js:12940:19)
    at Object.AST.multiplicative (http://localhost:21845/Scripts/angular.js:12927:21)
    at Object.AST.additive (http://localhost:21845/Scripts/angular.js:12918:21)
    at Object.AST.relational (http://localhost:21845/Scripts/angular.js:12909:21)
    at Object.AST.equality (http://localhost:21845/Scripts/angular.js:12900:21)
    at Object.AST.logicalAND (http://localhost:21845/Scripts/angular.js:12892:21) <select ng-disabled="true" ng-init="{{obj.ApproveID=selectedApproveStatus.DropdownUtilityID}}" ng-model="selectedApproveStatus" data-ng-options="option.DropdownUtilityName for option in approveStatus track by option.DropdownUtilityID" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
```

Comment: You do not need `{{` in `ng-init`

Comment: functionality not working when I remove the braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Syntax for `ng-init` is `ng-init="expression"`, you should not wrap it in `braces({{)`

Try this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Approve Status:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select ng-disabled="true" ng-init="obj.ApproveID=selectedApproveStatus.DropdownUtilityID" ng-model="selectedApproveStatus" data-ng-options="option.DropdownUtilityName for option in approveStatus track by option.DropdownUtilityID" class="form-control"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the error is not showing but when I change dropdown option value is not coming to obj.ApproveID..

Comment: is obj in your scope?

Comment: It seems you want to asign value to obj.ApproveID when you change your selection. Then use ng-change

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh, _Exactly_!

Comment: Well in that case, why do you want `ng-init`, just set the model value. that's it...

Comment: ng-init to initialize values from View. Mainly we use it very less.

Comment: What is the point of doing so ? In case, OP needs it to refer it anywhere else then still, why in view ?